# How to answer to new client's requests while having no time to work for them?

Tags: communication, time-management, clients

As you may have already read [I had health problems](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/how-to-deal-with-sudden-health-problem), I was K.O. for 3 weeks and it was a big problem for my job for many reasons... I am still having right now hard times to keep up with previous enstablished schedules and deadlines, but I am managing the situation (more or less) well.

The "problem" is that I am getting contacted for new jobs from old and new clients, but they don't know about my situation and what happened in this last period.

I have almost no time left to work on new projects in the short term, but I don't want to ignore them and also I don't want to decline possible good jobs.

I was thinking to answer them explaining my situation and maybe ask if they can wait some weeks, I'll be glad to work for them, but I don't know if this is the right approach.

Should I tell them about my health issues and hope for their understanding? Should I just say that I am too busy in this moment? Should I just say I would be available after a certain date? How would you answer?

PS: I was thinking about hiring some freelance or ask for help to collegues, but for some things the clients wants me, wants to meet me and interact with me during the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can´t take on more work, for whatever reason, just state that you are currently fully booked and possibly when you expect to be free again.

Don´t tell any personal stuff.

If you have more people competing for you time than you can serve, you should also look at increasing prices, especially if it´s not something you could hand over to another person.